# Huawei Site Kit no responde

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Estoy combinando Huawei Map kit y Site Kit para que cuando el usuario haga clic en algún punto de interés pueda cargar un diálogo con su información. El problema es que Site Kit no me está devolviendo nada y en el Logcat me manda el error 6004. Ya revisé ese error y dice que es un problema de caché o permisos. Ya limpié la caché, agregué los permisos necesarios al AndroidManifest y revisé que Site Kit estuviera habilitado en la consola pero sigue sin funcionar, este es mi código:

Estoy implementando la interfaz HuaweiMap.OnPoiClickListener para obtener el punto de interés que selecciona el usuario

```
override fun onPoiClick(poi: PointOfInterest) {
        Log.i("OnPoiClick", "Id: ${poi.placeId}")
        val apiKey = AGConnectServicesConfig
            .fromContext(this)
            .getString("client/api_key")

        val encodedApi = URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())

        // Declare a SearchService object.
        val searchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(this, encodedApi)
        // Create a request body.
        val request = DetailSearchRequest().apply {
            siteId = poi.placeId
        }
        // Create a search result listener.
        val resultListener: SearchResultListener<DetailSearchResponse> =
            object : SearchResultListener<DetailSearchResponse> {

                // Return search results upon a successful search.
                override fun onSearchResult(result: DetailSearchResponse?) {
                    Log.i("Site", "onSearchResult")
                    var site: Site? = null
                    if (result == null || result.site.also { site = it } == null) {
                        return
                    }
                    site?.let {
                        displayPlaceInformation(it)
                    }
                }

                // Return the result code and description upon a search exception.
                override fun onSearchError(status: SearchStatus) {
                    Log.i("Site", "Error : ${status.getErrorCode()}  ${status.getErrorMessage()}")
                }
            }
        // Call the place detail search API.
        searchService.detailSearch(request, resultListener)
    }
```

Si el servicio devuelve un lugar lo despliego en un Dialog

```
private fun displayPlaceInformation(site: Site) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
            setTitle(site.name)
            val message = "${site.formatAddress}\n\n${site.poi.phone}\n\n${site.poi.websiteUrl}"
            val formattedMessage = message.replace("\n\nnull", "")
            setMessage(formattedMessage)
            setCancelable(false)
            setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, _ ->
                dialogInterface.dismiss()
            }
        }.create().show()
    }
```

Pero no se ejecuta ninguno de los callbacks de SearchResultListener, sólo aparece el error 6004 en el Logcat

Estoy usando esta versión de SiteKit 'com.huawei.hms:site:5.1.0.300'. Cuál puede ser el problema?

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar esta información : https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve agregando el AppId en un meta-data dentro de tu AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid"
android:value="appid=******"/>
```

En algunas ocasiones, el plugin de AppGallery Connect no logra reconocer el AppId, lo que genera un error de autenticación contra los servidores de HMS.

Este paso solía estar documentado en las guías de HMS Core V4, pero al pasar a V5 ya no lo incluyeron. Si queres consultar la fuente de este fix te dejo el [enlace](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201290703112270097)